# Mysql order by and group by for a feed table

Tags: mysql

I am trying to do a group by and order by in mysql but am not getting the results I need. Here is my table structure
Table name is feed
id, date, user_id, item_id, item_type
It is a table for a feed of activity on a site.
I want the main feed to have the latest item that each user has posted but limit to only the latest post not all of their posts.

Here is the simple mysql query that I tried

select * from feed group by user_id order by date desc

I only get one post from each user but it is  not their latest post and it's not in order from the newest to oldest.

Comment: Can you provide sample data? It's impossible to see what's going on without know the column types, etc.

Comment: To add, group by will simply pick a random row for each unique value in the user_id column. Your order by clause is only applied AFTER that, which simply orders the values pulled at that point, except the values pulled are a random one for each user, so it's not going to actually do what you want it to do.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the latest post has the max value of feed_id, the following query should give you what you need:

```
SELECT f.* 
FROM feed f 
JOIN (SELECT user_id, max(feed_id) as feed_id FROM feed group by user_id) g 
on f.feed_id = g.feed_id
```